# strange c# syntax i'm trying to understand (taken from SilkProject MileageStats App)

Tags: c#

```
   Using<GetFillupById>().Execute(id);
```

never saw such syntax.
definition of Using is:

```
protected T Using<T>() where T : class
    {
        var handler = serviceLocator.GetInstance<T>();
        if (handler == null)
        {
            throw new NullReferenceException("Unable to resolve type with service locator; type " + typeof(T).Name);
        }
        return handler;
    }
```

if someone can tell me what exactlythis thing is- function, property?
or show me some link where i can read about -
I will appreciate

Comment: What _exactly_ don't you understand?

Comment: "such syntax" "this thing" - you haven't given us to know what your difficulty is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method/function uses a service locator to provide an instance of type `T`, returning that instance so it can be called. It's analgous to this:

```
new GetFillupById().Execute(id);
```

but instead of a default constructor call, this helper method wraps up the object initialisation and delegates it to a service locator object. The use of generics allows this to be used as a single method call for any type recognised by the service locator.

The type constraint `where T : class` means that this method can be validly called for any type `T` which is a class rather than a structure, i.e. a reference rather than a value type. The converse would be `where T : struct`. You can also include constraints to say `T` must implement a particular interface, extend a certain class, or expose a default constructor (`where T : new()`).

Related concepts to look up: generics, inversion of control.

Comment: thanks to everybody, but i still did not quite understand " where T: class"

Answer (score 1):

It is generic method of some class.

You can find more info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Its Generic Methods...

MSDN : [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb(v=vs.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This (`Using<T>`) is a [generic method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). For an introduction to generic methods, have a look at this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the SO html parser has eaten your `<T>` and that the method looks like this:

```
protected T Using<T>() 
    where T: class 
{ 
    var handler = serviceLocator.GetInstance(); 

    if (handler == null) 
    { 
        throw new NullReferenceException("Unable to resolve type with service locator; type " + typeof (T).Name); 
    } 

    return handler; 
}
```

Either that or this method was inside a generic class (otherwise there is no type specified for T)

There are plenty of generic types in C#

Check out `System.Collections.Generic`

A type you may have seen is `List<T>` which allows you to create a strongly typed list of type `T`

e.g.

```
var myList = new List<int>(); // This is a strongly typed list of int - if you call myList.Add() the Add will expect an int as the first parameter - at design time an error will be raised if the a non compatible type is used
```

Check out the info in Prateeks link in his answer